# Не загружается библиотека AIOGRAM

Tags: python, aiogram, pycharm

Загружаю библеотеку aiogram для бота через powershell.Выдает такую ошибку(фото 1)

[image: фото 1]

а если загружаю через GITBush,то он их видит,но в библиотеке папки их нет

Comment: А где тут загрузка библиотеки? Вы пытаетесь активировать виртуальное окружение, откройте cmd, посредством `cd` перейдите в `project/venv/scripts/` и пропишите `activate.bat` чтобы его активировать

Comment: Спасибо.Все сработало,но в библиотеке (в папке)aiogram не загрзился((Про библиотеку завис и не мог долго вспомнить как процесс называется))